# No extension exist for r:eval

Tags: r, siddhi, stream-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to run the RScriptSample present in the samples in the Stream Processor.

I've followed the steps given [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-gpl-execution-r/blob/master/README.md).

I have installed R and rJava, and set R_HOME and JRI_HOME accordingly.

```
@App:name("RScriptSample")
@App:description('Use a R script to process events and produce aggregated outputs based on the provided input variable parameters and expected output attributes.')

define stream weather (time long, temp double);

@sink(type='log')
define stream dataOut (time long, temp double, c long, m double );

@info(name = 'query') 
from weather#window.lengthBatch(2)#r:eval("c <- sum(time); m <- sum(temp)", "c long, m double", time, temp)
select * insert into dataOut;
```

The code does not compile. I'm getting this error in the last line.

```
No extension exist for r:eval
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since this extension is under GPL extension, it is not copied to the pack by default. Add the [jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.extension.siddhi.gpl.execution.r/siddhi-gpl-execution-r) to {SP_HOME}/lib folder and try out the sample.
Compatible Version: 4.x.x

Comment: I have done that too. Like I said, I followed the steps mentioned in README.md

Comment: What is the version of the extension you added?

Comment: This is what I added: siddhi-gpl-execution-r-3.2.0.jar

Comment: Version 3.2.0 is based on Siddhi-3.x and is incompatible with Stream Processor, try the 4.0.14

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Issue persists.

Comment: Was there any error logs when you restarted the pack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194701/discussion-between-dilip-sundar-and-niveathika).